# Minimum value in a named Range keeps returning an incorrect value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet of over a million rows of data and am trying to determine the minimum value in a temporary named range. However, it keeps return a `0` value, when all the values in the range are more than `1`. As a second check I have used the `Min` formula on the excel spreadsheet and checked that the minimum value is in fact higher than `1`

Below is my **Excel VBA code**

```
Sub MinValuesTemRange()

    ' Macro determines the minimum value in a temporary range

    'Step 1: Declare variables
    Dim CloseOutRange As Range
    Dim CloseOutCell As Range

    'Step 2: Define the Target Range
    Set CloseOutRange = Range("U8:U10201")

   'Step 3: Start looping through the range
    For Each CloseOutCell In CloseOutRange
        CloseOutCell.Select

        If CloseOutCell.Value > 0 Then
            'Step 4: Define the temporary variables for row and column numbers for the temporary Range
            Dim TempRowNrStart As Integer
            Dim TempColNr As Integer
            Dim TempRowNrLast As Integer

            'Step 5: Obtain the already calculated number of blank cells between closeOutCells having values
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.Select

            Dim BlankCells As Integer
            BlankCells = ActiveCell.Value

            'Step 6: Obtain the row number and column number of the active cell in Column B, the last row of the required range
            ActiveCell.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12).Range("A1").Select
            TempRowNrLast = ActiveCell.Row
            TempColNr = ActiveCell.Column
            TempRowNrStart = ActiveCell.Row - Temp

            'Step 7: Name the temporary range
            Range(Cells(TempRowNrStart, TempColNr), Cells(TempRowNrLast, TempColNr)).Name = "MyRange"

            'Step 8: Insert the minimum value in the desired cell
            ActiveCell.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRange)
        End If

    'Step 7: Get the next cell in the range
    Next CloseOutCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe the fields are formatted as text

Comment: You should avoid using `Select`, `ActiveCell`, instead use fully qualified `Cells` and `Range`. Also, what is this `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Range("A1").Select` suppose to be ? what are you trying to do with this line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your code; which has a lot of issues... 
 
1_ For each cell in the range in column "U" if it is >0; you use `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Range("A1").Select` (Don't need .Range("A1" or .Select) 
 
2_ You set variable `Dim BlankCells As Integer BlankCells = ActiveCell.Value` but don't use it. 
 
3_ You then offset again, `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12).Range("A1").Select` 
 
4_ With 1 and 3 you are actually offsetting -16 columns which would put you in column "E" not Column "B", like you say in your comments 
 
5_ You then try to set up a temporary range from the active cell in column "E"; but you never defined the variable "Temp" in `TempRowNrStart = ActiveCell.Row - Temp`, if the "Temp" variable is grater than 8 your code will fail because you start your range on cell U8 making it less than than 0 rows. 
 
6_ Breaking the line of code in which you try to define your temporary range, "MyRange" `Range(Cells(TempRowNrStart, TempColNr), Cells(TempRowNrLast, TempColNr)).Name = "MyRange"` 
 
7_ Then you try to write the minimum value into the Column "R" (13 columns from column "E") on the row you are checking.

If you were actually trying to accomplish what I understand from this confusion, check out my code. It is just a guide to help you, if it doesn't help you, update your question to be more clear about what you are trying to accomplish.

```
Sub test()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim MinValCel As Range
Dim MinVal As Long

For Each cell In Range("U8:U10201")
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(, -16).Select

        'set up cell to hold the minimum value
        Set MinValCel = ActiveCell.Offset(, 13)

        'set up MyRange
        Set myRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0)) 'Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0))
        'MsgBox myRange.Address (used to test the range)

        'set up Min worksheetfunction
        MinVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRange)

        'write the minimum value from range
        MinValCel.Value = MinVal
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("myRange"))

Comment: why not? I'm formatting the code, and you are write the answer while I'm writing the full answer ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado, and I was being stopped by some “duplicated” alert!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will get you the minimum value in column "U" for all positive values in that column.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub MinValuesTemRange()

    ' Macro determines the minimum value in a temporary range

    ' Step 1: Declare variables
    Dim CloseOutRange As Range
    Dim CloseOutCell As Range

    Dim PositiveRng As Range

    ' Step 2: Define the Target Range
    Set CloseOutRange = Range("U8:U10201")

    ' Step 3: Start looping through the range
    For Each CloseOutCell In CloseOutRange
        If CloseOutCell.Value > 0 Then
            If Not PositiveRng Is Nothing Then
                Set PositiveRng = Application.Union(PositiveRng, CloseOutCell)
            Else
                Set PositiveRng = CloseOutCell
            End If
        End If
    Next CloseOutCell

    ' check if there is at least 1 cell in column U with positive value
    If Not PositiveRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Min value is :" & WorksheetFunction.Min(PositiveRng)
    Else
        MsgBox "All cells in column 'U' are empty or less than 0", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

*Result when running this code with the sample of data in my column U*

[image]